# How do I shorten my code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, organization

I currently have a huge code for regenerating some things in a game a made. The code is very big and I think it can be compressed but I don't know how to do it. This is the code
    Private Sub regen()

```
    'regen coins
    z = coin1



     z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()


    z = coin2


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin3


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin4


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin5


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin6


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin7


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin8


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin9

    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin10


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin11


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin12


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin13


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin14


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin15


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin16


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin17


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin18


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin19


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin20


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin21


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin22


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin23


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin24


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin25


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin26


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin27


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin28


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin29


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin30


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin31


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin32


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    'regen medcoins

    p = medcoin1


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin2

    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin3


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin4


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin5


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin6


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin7


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()



    'regens hcoins

    h = hcoin1


    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()

    h = hcoin2



    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()

    h = hcoin3


    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()



End Sub
```

As you can see it is a bunch of code.

Comment: have you heard of arrays?

Comment: Looks like you're following the DRY principle well

Comment: Im new to this so I need help. I kind of know arrays but not very good and I have no idea on how to make the z variable change each time

Comment: -1. You need a "loop".  And if you've "written a game", you'd know about loops.  If you have a homework question, that's fine - but you should tell us this is homework so you get an answer that _explains_ what you need to do.  We're not your staff, nor are we stupid.

Comment: I think that Codereview would be a better fit for this. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How would I make a loop that changes the z variable every time

Comment: I think you really need to learn to use Google to learn about coding before you post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and pass the coins into it:

```
Sub DoStuff(z as coin)
     z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()
End Sub
```

then call it from elsewhere

```
DoStuff (coin1)
DoStuff (coin2)
DoStuff (coin3)
```

You may also want to read about arrays...

Comment: This seems like it will work but I get 1 error on (Byval z as coin) highlighting the word coin that says type coin is not defined

Comment: You need to create a coin class. Or modify the code suggested here as appropriate so it will work for you.

Comment: Change `(z as coin)` to `(z as <whatever data type z is>)`

Comment: I fixed it! I make the function z as object and now my code is just 50 lines thank you!!